# Reversing stacking order in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Before in bootstrap 2 you could reverse the stacking order in the grids by reversing the floats.

In bootstrap 3 this does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me the solutions for bootstrap 3?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reverse the floats on their examples, worked like a charm. something else might be wrong for you.

Comment: Reversing floats doesn't work in Bootstrap 3, confirmed. Bass Jobsen's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 16):

Use the  `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` modifier classes., see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

**example**:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7" style="height:50px;background-color:green;">first right</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5" style="height:100px;background-color:red;">second left</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

in Bootstrap 3 you can use **col-md-push-** and **col-md-pull-**.

Here is full code. 

I hope this will solve your problem.

```html
<html><head>
 <title>Bootstrap in practice: the grid system</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- To better visualize the columns -->
 <style>
 .row > div {
  background-color: #dedef8;
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;
 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">I was left</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">I was right</div>
 </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

**Run this Code in separate HTML page**

Here is snapshot
[image]